# Install Pillow for Python 3

Tags: 13.10, python3

What's the best way to install Pillow for Python 3?

Answer (score 10):

I tried using setuptools, but was [unsuccessful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426920/problem-installing-pillow-for-python-3-importerror-cannot-import-name-imaging).  But here's another method:

## Get pip for Python 3

Open a terminal and enter

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

## Get the dependencies

Install dependencies listed in Pillow's [docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-setuptools
sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
```

## Install Pillow

For Ubuntu 13.10+,

```
sudo pip3 install Pillow
```

and for 13.04-,

```
sudo pip-3.2 install Pillow
```

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 17.10..   Thanks alot..